# full text search with and condition

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

Is it possible to include `AND`, `OR`, `NOTIN` conditions with text search in MongoDB?

e.g.

```
final DBObject textSearchCommand = new BasicDBObject();
textSearchCommand.put("text", "user");
textSearchCommand.put("search", fullTextSearch.text)
textSearchCommand.put("isDeleted", false)\\ this is AND condition here, but this does not work
final CommandResult commandResult = db.command(textSearchCommand);
```

Is there any work around for this ?

Comment: You have 2 questions in your post could you reformulate this to be clearer?

Answer (score 0):

You have not maintained it clearly that do you want AND operation for all fields or you want first two fields in OR Operation and last fields i.e isDeleted is in AND operation with first two.

I'm considering you want All Three Fields in AND Operation

You case use AND , OR operator in mongodb to query on full text.

NOTIN i.e. $nin operator you have to use with particular field.

Below is code with $and operator in mongodb

```
        final BasicDBList textSearchCommand = new BasicDBList();

       /* List is used to add element  */

        textSearchCommand.add( new BasicDBObject("text", "user"));
        textSearchCommand.add( new BasicDBObject("search", fullTextSearch.text));
        textSearchCommand.add( new BasicDBObject("isDeleted", false));        


        BasicDBObject queryDoc = new BasicDBObject("$and", textSearchCommand);
       /* Above Statement Adds and operator to query */

        final CommandResult commandResult = db.command(queryDoc);
```

You can use $or same as like $and.

NotIn operator i.e. $nin used with particular field.

Following Are the links you can use reference.

And Operator : [$and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/]) 
OR Operator  : [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)
NOTIN Operator : [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)